How to display all locks from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
How to get around the message

10 LOCKS PRINTED FOR THIS TRX: SUPPRESSING FURTHER PRINTS

from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS in MySQL 8?
I tried searching but haven't found anything.
My main goal is to be able to see what is locked and how, in order to be able to update the locking queries to make sure they only lock what I expect it to. Currently the locking is too aggressive.
